# Не рабочая часть кода,что посоветуете сделать

Tags: c#, visual-studio

```
  if(start.Day == 30 &&(new int[]{3,5,7,9,11}).contains(start.Month) ||
                start.Day == 28 && start.Month == 1) {
                start.Day = 1;
                start.addMonths(1);
            } else {
                start.addDays(1);
            }
```

Comment: Тут нет ошибок, все работает как вы написали.

Comment: Замените `[3, 5, 7, 9, 11]` на `(new int[] { 3, 5, 7, 9, 11})`

Comment: ТС, а расскажите откуда вы скопировали данный код? Из `JAVA`?

Comment: @ヒミコ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1015490/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-c-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%b8-exel-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%81-3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что компилятор не понимает, что Вы подразумеваете под

```
[3, 5, 7, 9, 11]
```

исправьте на

```
(new int[] { 3, 5, 7, 9, 11}).contains(start.Month)
```

И должно заработать.

Comment: Каждый раз создавать массив? Не лучше сделать `private static Hashset<int>` или вовсе просто 5 условий в `if`?

Comment: конечно лучше, но для краткости ответа (и исходя из самой формулировки вопроса) решил написать таким образом.

Comment: Исходя из формулировки, можно было ответить просто — «Сможем!»

Comment: Александр Даниловский,Спасибо за помощь Правда не сработало,Может ещё какието советы есть